# Problema com quebra de linha JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

O problema é o seguinte, ao quebrar a linha no `textarea` na *div* `.result` onde é suposto aparecer o resultado daquilo que se digita na `textarea`, ele apenas da um espaço e não quebra a linha.

Como faço para que ele quebre a linha quando uma eu pular a mesma no textarea
Segue o meu código abaixo:

```js
$('.text').keyup(function(e) {
 $('span.result').html( $('.text').val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea name="" class='text' placeholder='texto'></textarea>
<br/>
<span class='result'>texto</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que a linha quebre é necessário utilizar a propriedade `word-wrap: break-word;` no seu código CSS da seguinte forma:

```
.result {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

> Mais informações sobre esta propriedade em: [CSS3 word-wrap Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)